# How can I make my app fit on all IOS devices?

Tags: ios, xcode, resize

I've read quite a few threads on S/O and have seen quite a few options for resizing your screen so that it works on iphone 4/5/6/ipad, etc.

My problem is, I'm making a game that relies a ton on collision and it seems like it would be a nightmare to have to resize it manually 3 or 4 times. Is there a way to do it simply in 1 view controller? I'm not sure if an autoresizingMask would work or not.

Comment: You can take use of Auto Layout

Answer (score 0):

One of the best solutions to this is to use AutoLayout.

I suggest reading more about AutoLayout [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html).